# Youtube video comment retrieval

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For getting video comments I use this example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&' .
   'videoId=' . $video->id . '&maxResults=100&' .
   'key=' . $ytApp->apiKey;
```

My question is: are there other filters except `maxResults` so I can get only the last comments of a video filter it by a date, or another filter that I can get only last comments not all comments or 100 comments per page?

Answer (score 2):

order     string
The order parameter specifies the order in which the API response should list comment threads. Valid values are:
time - Comment threads are ordered by time. This is the default behavior.
relevance - Comment threads are ordered by relevance.

Comment: order=time filter comments desc order. this is good but i want to filter by a date, for instance i want to get all comments made today in a video not previous comments. How to do that?